# Cloud 9 ide problems

Tags: cloud9-ide

I'm currently using c9.io as a IDE to work with a friend on a project.

My problem is that when i attempt to view the project i get an infinite loading loop followed by this.

[Cloud nine error](http://gyazo.com/21b665d041a9c521be0f516ba5723eb1)

So yeah. Development cannot really continue until this can get fixed or whatever. Its a huge spanner in the works for me.

What can i do? Is there any other alternatives to working real time with a buddy?

Thanks,

Taylor.

Comment: Does the Cloud9 Run documentation at https://docs.c9.io/run_an_application.html help? If not, can you share some code that could explain why you get into the infinite loading loop you mention?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but this solution worked for me:

https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/restarting-your-workspace

> You can also do this by appending ?reset=1 to your workspace URL. For
>   example, if my workspace URL is
>   https://ide.c9.io/username/workspace_name then I'd want to change it
>   to https://ide.c9.io/username/workspace_name?reset=1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the situation I've experienced which sounds like the issue you noticed and a solution that has worked for me:

**Issue:** 
You clicked to open a workspace and get the usual loading screen with the c9 logo and ajax loader in the center. This is normal until you realize the page never loads.

**Solution:** 
At this point, go ahead and clear your cookies. Then login to c9.io and access your workspace.

**Alternate solution:** 
Logout of c9 on your current browser. Open a different browser than the one currently running the infinite loading workspace. Login to your account and open the workspace.